# magento theme not loading file

Tags: layout

I have magento website at this [link](http://sw-sol-world.com/clients/pet/):

It's not loading shopper theme files. Theme original look is:-

http://sw-sol-world.com/clients/pet/index.php/home/?___store=default

What should I do in theme settings? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you are missing your `skin` folders/files. Make sure you have those files in place.

First check that you have correctly configured `theme` settings in `settings > configuration > design`. In **Package** section you should have `theme_pack_name` and in others part simply add your `theme_name`. Remember they should be accurate.

If these settings are fine then check your `skin` folder.
Basically skin files should be in following tree format:

```
/skin/frontend/theme_pack/theme_name/skin
/skin/frontend/theme_pack/theme_name/js
/skin/frontend/theme_pack/theme_name/images
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: please check these paths
http://sw-sol-world.com/clients/pet/skin/frontend/default/shopper/css/local.css
http://sw-sol-world.com/clients/pet/skin/frontend/default/shopper/css/styles.css
skin folder and files are already here
also settings > configuration > design settings are fine

Comment: then check first case - `settings > configuration > design` area.

Comment: and make sure, you have cleaned your cache.

Comment: settings > configuration > design area. is fine and i flushed cache as well but nothing happens